# ActiveRecord index_by Precedence for Duplicate Keys

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

When using `index_by` on a relation with duplicate values for the key, is there a guarantee as to what value with have precedence?

```
users = User.all  #=> [<User id: 1, name: 'Jane'>, <User id: 2, name: 'Jane'>]
users_by_name = users.index_by(&:name)
```

Can I be certain 100% of the time as to the value of

```
users_by_name['Jane'] #=> User#1? User#2? Random?
```

Answer (score 1):

The last element takes precedence.

If you try to sort users collection by `id ASC` and `id DESC` you will notice the difference.

```
User.all.order('id  ASC').index_by(&:name) # => {'Jane' => {id:2}}
User.all.order('id DESC').index_by(&:name) # => {'Jane' => {id:1}}
```

Answer (score 1):

`index_by` isn't ActiveRecord, it's from ActiveSupport (see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#index-by)

> Keys should normally be unique. If the block returns the same value for different elements no collection is built for that key. The last item will win.